# Pivot table in excel contain duplicate data (not sure if it MS Excel Bug)

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-pivot

[image]

In Excel, I'm getting duplicate values one with a check and one with unchecked when I create a pivot table.(see the attached excel screen)

Please help me with this.

Comment: May be there are some non printable characters in your source for which it might be duplicating

Comment: Oh did you see the screen that I attached? that contains special some special characters, however those characters are also present in other values and pivot was not repeating those !

Comment: I meant to say non printable characters like like CHAR 160 127 etc, which cant be seen through naked eyes, we need to use a formula, have you imported the data from any DBMS or SAP or any ERP?

Comment: yes the data imported from DBMS , What will be solution for this ?

Comment: Use `SUBSTITUTE()` Function to substitute `CHAR(160)` with `""` in your source for the specific column.